# Kivy: play sound on android without delay

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy, buildozer

I'm creating a metronome app with kivy. Since the ticks need to be exactly on point I ran in a lot of issues.

I sheduled the clock-events as "free" events:

```py
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'free_all')
Config.write()

Clock.schedule_once_free(self.callback, self.delay)
```

If I trace the timings of the callbacks they are all great.
The widgets are updated in these callbacks and they are just on point.

But if I play a sound on the start of the callback it gets executed with different delays every time. So the sound does not relate to the intented bpm.

Different Sound-loaders have different behavior:
"SoundPygame" doesn't have a delay but can't be used for android (missing support for pygame)
The non-kivy module "play sound" works great, but can't be used with a buildozer because of missing module "gi".
"SoundSDL2" is used by default and does not work for this task.

```py
sound_norm = SoundPygame(source='sounds/tick.wav')

def callback(self, dt):
    self.sound_norm.play()
```

Is there any way to play sound on android with kivy without event-based delays?

It's my first question here, so please excuse me if I asked something wrong or need to improve my question.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pyjnius soved the problem. I now have platform depandant code.
For Android:

```py
from jnius import autoclass

MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
mPlayer_norm = MediaPlayer()
mPlayer_norm.setDataSource(SOUND_NORM)
mPlayer_norm.prepare()
```

later I can play the sound in the callback:

```py
self.sound_norm.play()
```

This way there is no noticable delay so it works for me.